# flask dummy web app example

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I have written a python script (currently, it only runs locally) that creates a plot and then stores it on my local computer. How can a transform this into a web app using flask? Should I "upload" the image somewhere?

Comment: If you're going to be serving the image you should just keep the file local and setup flask so that it returns the image every time it gets a specific request. Another way would be to upload the image to some cloud service and when you receive a request return the link to download the file. Defuz's example demonstrates the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest option to do this:

```
from flask import send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_image')
def get_image():
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/gif')

app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that there is something missing though since it doesn't work yet... What's more, how can I make my app such that the user gives some parameters for the generation of the plot?